# Wordpress & MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I think I am asking the most short minded question on the world: I have a site created in wordpress. I have on the site a form (Contact form7) and a contact form as well as a MySQL DB with my host provider. I have no idea how to connect the website form to the MySQL. All I got in the last week from internet are php codes. Happy to replicate those, but where am I entering them/which file, which folder? you see, I am really new!!! Thanks you, Mario

Comment: Try the installing howto from wordpress https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/

Comment: This is a bit broad. Start with a book or tutorial.